# Getting Parse error in CSV LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to upload a CSV file in Database with PHP script.
the query am writing for that is

```
mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'data.csv' INTO TABLE  `raw_data` FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ',' ENCLOSED BY  '"' ESCAPED BY  '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ");
```

The error i am getting while running this script is

```
Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\price\godata.php on line 5
```

Can any1 tell me where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Perhaps it's the apostrophes (!= quotes) here: ` `raw_data` `, the other quotes seem to be escaped properly, imho

Comment: @djot No, backticks ` are the correct thing to use in mysql when selecting tables, columns etc.

Comment: @Fluffeh Perhaps I remember incorrectly, but I had problems with them also ... and you might guess it, that's why I avoid them ;)

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, you are using a double quote `"` inside a string terminated by double quotes. You will need to escape the character, which you can do like this:

```
mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'data.csv' INTO TABLE  `raw_data` 
             FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ',' ENCLOSED BY  '\"' ESCAPED BY  '\\' 
             LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ");         // ^ PHP Thought your command 
                                                  // ended at that point
```

Comment: Why escape double quotes inside single qoutes?

Comment: @djot Because the string that is the command is encapsulated by double quotes.

Comment: \@Fluffeh You're right ... (I never use double quotes ... or avoid them for several reasons) ... I have to escape the "@" here also ;))))

Answer (score -1):

Put escape `\` character before `"` ie replace **ENCLOSED BY  '"'** by **ENCLOSED BY  '\"'**